# How to identify general medical terms using Wikipedia/DBpedia/WikiData

Tags: uses-of-open-data, research, linked-data, rdf, ontology

Given a list of medical terms, I want to identify and remove the *general* (less granular) terms.

For example consider the below mentioned word list:

```
 - kartagener s syndrome 
 - disease treatment
 - human 
 - blood 
 - ischaemia
 - acute respiratory distress syndrome
 - hospital 
 - adrenergic blocking drug 
 - finger 
 - symptom 
 - therapy
 - extracorporeal membrane oxygenation 
 - hand
```

I mean word such as;

```
 - human
 - blood
 - disease treatment
 - hospital
 - finger
 - symptom
 - therapy
 - hand
```

as general/less granular terms.

I tried to detect these terms using the following two statistical measures.

- frequency: i.e. I assumed the more frequent the word in the corpus
  is, the less granular it is
- IDF (Inverse Document Frequency)

However, since they are only statistical measures and does not consider the meaning (semantics) of the word, it worked poorly in my dataset.

I tried to use wikipedia categories to filter these terms. However, I could not find a proper way of using categorical details to facilitate my problem. Therefore, I am wondering if there is any way to detect general terms using wikipedia (or its variants such as DBpedia, Wikidata etc.)

For those, who would like to check a long list of concepts, I have attcahed a long list herewith: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BYllMyDlw-Rb4uMh89VjLml2Bl9Y7oUlopM-Z4F6pN0/edit

*NOTE: I am not expecting the solution to work 100% (if the proposed algorithm is able to detect many of the general concepts that is enough for me)*

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: https://w.wiki/3Rm

Comment: Can you state why "finger" is in your list of less granular terms? I don't see a more specific concept. Also, your question states that wikipedia/data/dbpedia have to be used. While these are great resources, you may get more complete answers by using tools that use the UMLS, BioPortal, or Open Bio Ontologies (OBO).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a corpus of the general terms (I don't think it should be too big), if yes then the issue will automatically be resolved, the issue is at this point I am not certain what constitutes as a general term. Stainslav Kralsin's solution does look promising, but I haven't really used WQS, so I don't really know how that works, my suggestion would be to not use AI in this, rather create a corpus of general words and then use a regex approach.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I was able to understand most of the parts of your code. However, I am not clear what is meant by `?s`, `?p` in `?s ?p ?item .`. Could you please let me know what is denoted using this line? I look forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: The query just count the number of incoming links. Terms that are often "referenced" could be considered as "general".

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks a lot for your comment. So, `?s` and `?p` denotes `subject` and `predicate` in RDF graph? Please kindly correct me if I am wrong. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)